# Can an RxJS 5 Observable source be stopped by another down the chain?

Tags: rxjs, observable

`RxJS 5` `Angular 2 RC4` app written in `Typescript 1.9`:

I have two observables in a chain. I would like, if a condition is met in the 2nd, for the first to be completed immediately.  My efforts seem unnecessarily complex. In the example below, I try to stop the first observable after it has emitted 3 values:

```
source = Observable.interval(1000)
        .do(()=>this.print("*******EMITTING from Source*******"))
        .switchMap(count => {
            if(count<3){ //just pass along the value
                return Observable.create(observer=>{
                    observer.next(count);observer.complete()
                })                
            }
            else{ //abort by issuing a non-productive observable
                return Observable.create(observer=>
                    observer.complete()
                )
            }
        })
this.source.subscribe(count=>this.print('Ouput is '+count);
```

Here is the output:

```
*******EMITTING from Source*******
Output is 0
*******EMITTING from Source*******
Output is 1
*******EMITTING from Source*******
Output is 2
*******EMITTING from Source*******
*******EMITTING from Source*******
*******EMITTING from Source*******
```

So, functionally I get the result I want because the wider script stops getting notifications after three outputs. However, I'm sure there is a better way. My problems are:

1. The upstream observable continues to emitting forever. How can I stop it?
2. I'm creating a new observable down the chain on every emission. Shouldn't I be able to just pass along the first 3 values but abort or complete the chain on the 4th?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`take` operator](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-take) to do it.`take` takes the first N events and completes the stream.

```
this.source = Observable.interval(1000)
  .do(()=>this.print("*******EMITTING from Source*******"))
  .take(3);
this.source.subscribe(count=>this.print('Ouput is '+count);
```

Your example's stream doesn't complete because `switchMap`'s outer stream doesn't complete when inner streams complete. `switchMap()` is equal to `map().switch()`. In your example, the `map` part emits **observables** like:

1. next(0), complete()
2. next(1), complete()
3. next(2), complete()
4. complete()
5. complete()
6. complete()
7. complete()
8. ...(continues infinitely)...

And the `switch` part switches those observables and keeps waiting for upcoming observables.

**EDIT**

Your example also could be written as:

```
source = Observable.interval(1000)
        .do(()=>this.print("*******EMITTING from Source*******"))
        .takeWhile(count => count < 3);
```

**EDIT 2**

Regarding your comment, if you want to terminate the stream if the inner stream emits `true`:

```
source = Observable.interval(1000)
        .do(()=>this.print("*******EMITTING from Source*******"))
        .switchMap(count => createSomeObservable(count))
        .takeWhile(x => x !== true);
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. `.take()` works here (+1). I used this as a simple example though; my larger question is: how to (if possible) complete the 1st observable from the 2nd based on some condition.  for instance suppose I have 2 observables in a chain and I want to stop all work if the first Observable emits `true`.  Maybe what a `takeUntil()` would do

Comment: What do you mean by `2 observables in a chain`? Probably `takeXxx` operators will help you as you guess.

BTW this article was an eye-opener to me about `takeXxx` operators. https://medium.com/@benlesh/rxjs-dont-unsubscribe-6753ed4fda87#.tkmznu7ho

Comment: My OP has 2 observables in a chain (`switchMap` outputs the 2nd).  I'm just looking for a way to kill/complete the stream from within it and I bet an operator will let me do that. I'll read the article  you linked.

Comment: I added an example to terminate the stream if the inner `Observable` emits `true`.

Comment: You were right, that article along with your response here give me all I need. much appreciated.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that :-)